# Как вставить текст посередине другого текста

Tags: python, строки, текст

У меня есть переменная `text = 'Hello World'`
как я могу поместить что-то еще в случайном месте в этом тексте
чтобы на выходе я получил допустим `he11llo world`, `hello w1w3w world`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И так:

```
import random

text = 'Hello World'
i = random.randint(0, len(text))               # случайная позиция

text = text[:i] + "**что-то**" + text[i:]

print(text)
```

---

*Примеры выводов:*

> ```
> He**что-то**llo World
> Hello Wor**что-то**ld
> Hello World**что-то**
> Hell**что-то**o World
> **что-то**Hello World
> Hello Worl**что-то**d
> ```

---

*Примечание:*

Чтобы внести текст только во *внутреннюю* позицию (т.е. не в начало/конец), вместо

```
i = random.randint(0, len(text))               # случайная позиция
```

примените

```
i = random.randint(1, len(text) - 1)           # случайная внутренняя позиция
```

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. у типа `str` нету метода `insert`, то можно, как вариант, поиграться с типами:

```
a = list('lol')  # lol
a.insert(1, 'k')
print(''.join(a)) # lkol
```